# Noticing iconic SFX used in other movies...

Tags: reused

Couldn't help but notice that when I watched Looper last night, a very familiar sound was used that I instantly recognized from my childhood.

It was when the hovering motorcycles stall or crash. I'm pretty sure it's the same motor wind-down sound effect that was used in Star Wars for when the millennium falcon comically doesn't start for Han Solo.

I find this happening to me a lot, mostly with cliche sounds.. Like the anvil hit that gets used in almost every action movie trailer ever made...

So, what other sounds have you noticed that are iconic in some movies, I.e. used with good judgement and class, but when used in other projects, just sound a little off and not right for the part?

Comment: don't we have a thread like this somewhere already?

Comment: @Shaun, we have one somewhere buried 3 years deep about how much people hate the wilhelm scream and firebat SFX. My question is slightly different. ;)